# webpack not adding [contenthash] properly to my .js files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to set the hash of my files to reflect the content, so that they dont get cached.

The best/easiest way I found was by using `contenthast` on the file names, but when I try it, webpack adds it correctly to my `.css` and `.map` files, but not to my `.js files`

```
                         static/js/vendor.[contenthash].js     651 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
                           static/js/main.[contenthash].js     131 kB       1  [emitted]         main
                       static/js/manifest.[contenthash].js  869 bytes       2  [emitted]         manifest
      static/css/main.142c3dccf1d3eb2c02c84322b0cf2ef7.css     274 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  main
  static/css/main.142c3dccf1d3eb2c02c84322b0cf2ef7.css.map     545 kB          [emitted]         
  static/js/vendor.651ccaf8218b875738b87d472058ef85.js.map    2.78 MB       0  [emitted]         vendor
    static/js/main.1d8c83094a24fff4097ced4e4b947bd5.js.map     471 kB       1  [emitted]         main
static/js/manifest.76f2ac98b5b1630c96bf2b7aeb5b3498.js.map    4.96 kB       2  [emitted]         manifest
```

My `webpack.prod.conf.js` looks like:

```
/* eslint-disable */
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

const env = require('../config/prod.env')

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true,
      usePostCSS: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath(`js/[name].[contenthash].js`),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath(`js/[id].[contenthash].js`)
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      },
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      parallel: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath(`css/[name].[contenthash].css`),
      // Setting the following option to `false` will not extract CSS from codesplit chunks.
      // Their CSS will instead be inserted dynamically with style-loader when the codesplit chunk has been loaded by webpack.
      // It's currently set to `true` because we are seeing that sourcemaps are included in the codesplit bundle as well when it's `false`,
      // increasing file size: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1110
      allChunks: true,
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
        ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
        : { safe: true }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // keep module.id stable when vendor modules does not change
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // enable scope hoisting
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks (module) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    // This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
    // in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
    // see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'app',
      async: 'vendor-async',
      children: true,
      minChunks: 3
    }),

    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

And webpack.base.conf.js:

```
/* eslint-disable */
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js'],
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
    // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
    setImmediate: false,
    // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
    // that does not make sense for the client
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
}
```

more info can be found here in a bug ticket for webpack: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7884

Comment: if you remove that utils and pass the whole path directly, does that work? it has to be a string

Comment: @PlayMa256 if you mean like `filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash].js'`, then that outputs the same: `'js/main.[contenthash].js'`

Answer (score 12):

Try to use `[hash]` instead of `[contentHash]`. This worked for me

Answer (score 10):

I used a small letter "h" and it worked script.[contenthash].js

Comment: This worked for me.. not sure what happened though, as I always had it with capital H. Must be some recent update

Answer (score 5):

`[contenthash]` is used in some plugins like `extract-text-webpack-plugin` since their beginning, but unfortunately webpack started using `[contenthash]` only in webpack 4.

**tl;dr** since you are using webpack 3, then you have only one option, which is `[chunkhash]`

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue, I was naming my output file as `main.[contentHash].js` but changing it to `main.[contenthash].js` worked for me.